How to get data from a webpage that does not respond to GET
I am new to coding and I am learning to scrape webpages. My current project is to gather fuel prices from supermarkets. Data is available here. Since python scrapping failed when trying to retrieve data from this page. I tried to debug with curl and it seems the server blocks incoming scrape requests. Is there any other way to get the info needed?
⏺ ~ > curl -v "https://www.tesco.com/fuel_prices/fuel_prices_data.json" --http1.1
*   Trying 96.16.109.100:443...
* Connected to www.tesco.com (96.16.109.100) port 443
* ALPN: curl offers http/1.1
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
*  CApath: none
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Unknown (8):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / AEAD-CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256
* ALPN: server accepted http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=GB; L=Welwyn Garden City; jurisdictionCountryName=GB; O=Tesco PLC; businessCategory=Private Organization; serialNumber=00445790; CN=www.tesco.com
*  start date: Mar 20 13:08:28 2024 GMT
*  expire date: Apr 20 13:08:27 2025 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "www.tesco.com" matched cert's "www.tesco.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Entrust, Inc.; OU=See www.entrust.net/legal-terms; OU=(c) 2014 Entrust, Inc. - for authorized use only; CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1M
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* using HTTP/1.1
> GET /fuel_prices/fuel_prices_data.json HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.tesco.com
> User-Agent: curl/8.4.0
> Accept: */*

* Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
* LibreSSL SSL_read: LibreSSL/3.3.6: error:02FFF036:system library:func(4095):Connection reset by peer, errno 54
* Closing connection
* Send failure: Broken pipe
* Send failure: Broken pipe
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

Edit: py code to scrap
import requests

URL = "https://www.tesco.com/fuel_prices/fuel_prices_data.json"

page = requests.get(URL)

print(page.text)

Result:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/abjohnson/coding/pylab/beautiful_web_scraper.py", line 6, in <module>
    page = requests.get(URL)
  File "/Users/abjohnson/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/abjohnson/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/abjohnson/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Users/abjohnson/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/abjohnson/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 501, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', TimeoutError(60, 'Operation timed out'))


Interesting. Works fine with HTTPie. Either it's some subtle bug in the client-server interaction, or they're specifically blocking curl.

It looks like the server is filtering based on the User-Agent header in your request.
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': ('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/'
      '537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36Edg/123.0.0.0')
}

sess = requests.Session()
sess.headers.update(headers)
u = "https://www.tesco.com/fuel_prices/fuel_prices_data.json"
sess.get(u)
# returns:
<Response [200]>


Thank you for the solution. What headers do python requests use without specifying any ? because i didnt think of picking on headers(nor do i know what they do) from the curl output

the default user-agent is 'python-requests/2.31.0' for requests version 2.31.0

thank you for your solution. Learnt something new :)

@James You are correct that there's a default User-Agent in requests. Unfortunately, not all websites will accept it so it's best to use something that is a true reflection of what an up-to-date browser might use

As long as you provide an acceptable User-Agent requests can handle this:
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 14_1) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.2 Safari/605.1.15"
}
url = "https://www.tesco.com/fuel_prices/fuel_prices_data.json"

with requests.get(url, headers=headers) as response:
    response.raise_for_status()
    print(response.json())

Output:
Not shown because of its size but when testing, an expected JSON structure was acquired

Thank you. Is there a way to tell what user-agent headers does the server expect?

It is likely trying to parse the user agent, which have a fairly standard format.  if it fails, it returns an error code.

@j4son I don't think so. Just use anything that would be sent from a well-known browser. I don't know if this is kept fully up-to-date but you may find it useful

@SIGHUP, thank you for the solution. Its a shame that STACK allows me to choose only one answer.
